# More Efficient Way To Split a Balanced String C#

Tags: c#, string, string-parsing

I've done this with balancing Regex's before when I only had one balancing character...but with more balancing characters it gets more complicated and uglier.

For my current purpose, I instead wrote an method to do this by tokenizing the string but it's terribly slow (and terribly inefficient) The most expensive part seems to be the gratuitous Substring usage I'm doing (yeah I know it's bad).

Basically, I want to take the following

```
  hello("(abc d)", efg (hijk)) and,some more<%lmn, "o(\")pq", (xy(z))%>
```

and end up with

```
hello("(abc d)", efg (hijk)) 
[space] (the actual character)
and
,
some more
<%lmn, "o()pq", (xy(z))%>
```

In other words, I'm splitting on (and I want these included in the array results)

```
[space]
,
```

....and I have "balanced grouping strings"

```
" "
( )
<% %>
```

...and I have escape characters

```
\
```

I'd prefer not to write a whole big parser for this purpose...

Here's the code:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitNotEnclosed(this string s, IEnumerable<string> separators, Dictionary<string, string> enclosingValues = null, IEnumerable<char> escapeCharacters = null, bool includeSeparators = false, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.Ordinal)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();

        var enclosureStack = new Stack<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        bool atEscapedCharacter = false;

        if (escapeCharacters == null) escapeCharacters = new[] { '\\' };
        if (enclosingValues == null) enclosingValues = new[] { "\"" }.ToDictionary(i => i);

        var orderedEnclosingValues = enclosingValues.OrderByDescending(i => i.Key.Length).ToArray();
        separators = separators.OrderByDescending(v => v.Length).ToArray();

        var currentPart = new StringBuilder();

        while (s.Length > 0)
        {
            int addToIndex = 0;

            var newEnclosingValue = orderedEnclosingValues.FirstOrDefault(v => s.StartsWith(v.Key, comparisonType));

            if (enclosureStack.Count > 0 && !atEscapedCharacter && s.StartsWith(enclosureStack.Peek().Value))
            {
                addToIndex = enclosureStack.Peek().Value.Length;
                enclosureStack.Pop();
            }
            else if (newEnclosingValue.Key != null && !atEscapedCharacter)
            {
                enclosureStack.Push(newEnclosingValue);
                addToIndex = newEnclosingValue.Key.Length;
            }
            else if (escapeCharacters.Contains(s[0]) && enclosureStack.Count > 0)
            {
                atEscapedCharacter = !atEscapedCharacter;
                addToIndex = 1;
            }
            else if (enclosureStack.Count > 0)
            {
                atEscapedCharacter = false;
                addToIndex = 1;
            }

            if (enclosureStack.Count == 0)
            {
                string separator = separators.FirstOrDefault(v => s.StartsWith(v, comparisonType));

                if (separator != null)
                {
                    if (currentPart.Length > 0) results.Add(currentPart.ToString());
                    results.Add(separator);
                    s = s.Substring(separator.Length);
                    currentPart = new StringBuilder();

                    addToIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    addToIndex = 1;
                }
            }

            currentPart.Append(s.Substring(0, addToIndex));
            s = s.Substring(addToIndex);
        }

        if (currentPart.Length > 0) results.Add(currentPart.ToString());

        if (!includeSeparators)
        {
            results = results.Except(separators).ToList();
        }

        return results.ToArray();
    }
```